# Redirecting to an Action Method from another Action Method in the same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am a Newbie in asp.net and currently I am doing a web page application in MVC4 with Login functionality.
My Index action method looks like this-

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var PageModelList1 = new DataAccessLayer.DataAccess().GetPageInfo();
        ViewData["MenuList"] = PageModelList1.PageModelList;
        return View();
    }
```

and my LogIn action method looks like-

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(LogInModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var PageModelList1 = new DataAccessLayer.DataAccess().GetPageInfo(model.UserName,model.Password);
            ViewData["MenuList"] = PageModelList1.PageModelList;

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyController");
        }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "login failed");

        return PartialView("_LogIn", model);
    }
```

what I need is, when I Login successfully, the RedirectToAction("Index", "Deimos") should take place but the 'MenuList' there should be the new 'MenuList' from LogIn action method. How could I do it?

Comment: Instead of just passing a username and password along to the data store, learn about [Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) and log the user in properly - then in `Index` you can use `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and `User.Identity.Name` to fetch the appropriate information.

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectToAction` will send a 302 response to the browser with the new url as the location header value and browser will make a totally new request to go to that page. This new request has no idea what you did in the previous request. So `ViewData` will not work. You may consider using `TempData`.

**But TempData's life is only until the next request**. After that it is gone. So if you want something on all the subsequent requests(like a menu to be shown to user), I suggest you read it from a database table every time you load the page. You can store the items to a cache after the first read to avoid constant hit(s) to the database if you are worried about that.

Another option is to set the menu items to Session variables and read from there. I am not a big fan of setting stuff like that to session. I prefer to read it from a cache (in which data was loaded from a db call) or so.

Comment: I don't think any of these solutions are great (although the second paragraph is alluding to the right solution) - the problem calls for proper authentication, rather than some hack to allow data retrieved on the login post to be persisted over subsequent requests. Note that currently there is not really any "proper" auth going on here, just what appears to be retrieval of data via a composite key of username/password.

Comment: **but the 'MenuList' there should be the new 'MenuList' from LogIn action method**. I think he wants the data he is setting to view data which will not work when doing a Redirect. My answer is a pointer for which direction he should go .Of course he needs to take care of authentication. There are different ways to do that and he should be able to do that with a little internet search

Comment: *but the 'MenuList' there should be the new 'MenuList' from LogIn action method* - exactly; the pertinent point being that the login post is not the proper place to retrieve that information - that's being done there as a workaround to a lack of proper authentication (since the identity will be lost on the following request) and using session or other means to persist that to the following GET request is just a hack on top of a hack.